# jquery popup positioning issue

Tags: jquery, html, dialog, popup

[image]

How can I make the pop-up align just like the image below?
The current code is as follows:

```
        $("#jobActionsPopup").dialog({
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            position: { my: "middle top", at: "middle bottom", of: $("#jobActionsButton") },
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: true,
        }).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about you change `my: "middle top"` into `my: "right top"` and `at: "middle bottom"` into `at: "right bottom"`.

here is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/zz20935q/2/).